# Expand element horizontally with $.animate() and trigger window.resize as it expands

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I have a responsive carousel (using [CarouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/)) that expands from 49% width to 100% width on click and, upon animation completion, runs `$(window).trigger('resize')` to trigger the carousels built-in responsiveness.

However, because the trigger does not occur until the animation is complete, there is noticeable jumpiness.  Question: is there a way to trigger the window resize as the carousel expands, in effect mimicking a resizing window?

Example on CodePen: http://codepen.io/chrisrockwell/pen/uozCj

EDIT: The pen, after discussing with others, may not be very clear. So, I've added another that contains 2 alert statements - at the beginning and end of animation: http://codepen.io/chrisrockwell/details/Epuds

EDIT 2: CarouFredSel also has an [`updateSizes` event](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/custom-events.php), which I believe is the same as triggering resize on the window.  Regardless, I need the resize to be triggered multiple times as the carousel is 'growing'.

I hope the example makes it clear what I'm trying to do - if there is another way to accomplish outside of triggering resize please feel free to share.

This is the JavaScript/jQuery currently:

```
$container.on('click', function() {
  if ($container.hasClass('expanded'))
  {
    $(this).animate({
      width: '49%',
      left: '50%',
    }, 1000, function() {
      $(window).trigger('resize');
      $container.toggleClass('expanded')
    })
  }
  else
  { 
    $(this).animate({
      width: '100%',
      left: 0,
    }, 1000, function() {
      $(window).trigger('resize');
      $container.toggleClass('expanded')
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather trivial, after all.  [jQuery `animate()` has a `step` option](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) which is

> A function to be called for each animated property of each animated element. This function provides an opportunity to modify the Tween object to change the value of the property before it is set.

Basically, it allows you to provide a callback function for each step of the animation.  If I combine this with the [updateSizes custom event](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/custom-events.php) provided by the carousel plugin (which is essentially the same as triggering a window resize) it updates the size of the carousel as it's parent container expands.

Here is an example of the step option of animate doing it's thing: http://jsfiddle.net/DAMkg/1/

Here is the CodePen that illustrates the carousel expanding as it's parent expands: http://codepen.io/chrisrockwell/details/Epuds

And here is the relevant JavaScript with the step option added in.  Note that animate() now contains two simple objects, as opposed to one simple object, a variable for duration, and a callback function.

```
$(this).animate(
  {
    width: '100%',
    left: 0,
  }, 
  {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function(now, tween) {
      $carousel.trigger('updateSizes')
    },
    complete: function () {
      $container.toggleClass('expanded')
    }
   }
);
```